# How to get the desired output using awk in unix

Tags: unix, awk

I'm new to using awk, and I'm stuck on a problem.

I have a file:

```
startpoint--A
endpoint--B
startpoint--C
endpoint--D
```

I want the output as desired in a column so that under startpoint, I have all the start variables(A,C) and under endpoint all the end varibles(B,D). For example:

```
startpoint  endpoint
 A          B
 C          D
```

How can I accomplish this with awk?

Comment: Please elaborate on your question.  What exact form do you want the output in?

Comment: I've edited your question for form, but it's still very difficult to figure out what you are asking. Also, please use complete sentences, and employ proper grammar and spelling to the best of your ability.

Answer (score 1):

Presumably your data file alternates `startpoint` and `endpoint` lines.  In that case you can just save the most recent `startpoint` and print them both out when you encounter an `endpoint`.

```
$ cat data.txt
startpoint--A
endpoint--B
startpoint--C
endpoint--D

$ cat points.awk
BEGIN { print "startpoint  endpoint" }
$1 == "startpoint" { sp = $3 }
$1 == "endpoint" { printf "%-12s%s\n", sp, $3 }

$ awk -F- -f points.awk data.txt
startpoint  endpoint
A           B
C           D
```

Comment: wat does this infer awk -F- -f and wat is the point.awk scripts infering

Comment: @Sundhar `-F` is telling awk what to use for a field delimiter. You really need to be more clear in your questions and comments.

Comment: @Rick im not able to use the same solution for another file and it doesnt work the only change was instead of A B C D i have something like this on each start and end point LVISION_WTAP_INST/LVISION

Answer (score 0):

Don't need awk, `cut` and `paste` will do:

```
{
  printf "startpoint\tendpoint\n"
  cut -d '-' -f 3 data.txt | paste - -
} | column -t
```

I assume that all you data is "well-formed", with an endpoint immediately following a startpoint.